# Визуализация прогресса скачивания файла с сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На файлообменике MEGA есть интересная фишка, при нажатие на кнопку скачать, прогресс загрузки визуально отображается на странице, после окончания скачивания, файл уже на компьютере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API файловой системы](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) (полифил расширения Chrome / Firefox)

Adobe Flash SWF Filewriter (для старых браузеров)

[BlobBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE10 / IE11)

[MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)

(источник: https://eu.static.mega.co.nz/js/download_6.js)